# Checkbox Images in List

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, list, checkbox, itemrenderer

It seems like it should be a simple concept. I need a vertical list. This list has an image with a checkbox and pathname of that image underneath it. The user should be able to check the checkboxes of the images they want to appear in their "shopping cart". The images, checkbox label, and list are populated by an XmlList. How can I do this in Flex 3.5 and Actionscript and have a button that when clicked, display a list of the checked items??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a custom list item-renderer.

Here are same docs http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cellrenderer_2.html